# jQuery FullCalendar how to show data after ajax call without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to integrate jQuery FullCalendar with PHP and MySQL.. Problem for me is that when i'm inserting new event with by selecting day(s) with AJAX I don't know how to show this newly added event without refreshing page.. So basically this is the FullCalendar call:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    editable: true,
    firstDay: 1,

    header: {
        left: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'prev, next, today'
    },

    // receive events from DB
    events: {
        url: 'events.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        error: function() {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    },

    buttonIcons: {
        prev: 'left-single-arrow',
        next: 'right-single-arrow'
    },

    // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }

        element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + event.description);
    },

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {

        var start = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end   = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var user_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>

        // to unix
        start = moment(start).unix();
        end = moment(end).unix();

        $('#myModal').modal({
            remote: 'modals/add_event.php?start='+start+'&end='+end+'&id='+user_id
        });

    }           

});
```

The place where I'm doing event insertion is:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {

    var start = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var end   = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var user_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>

    // to unix
    start = moment(start).unix();
    end = moment(end).unix();

    $('#myModal').modal({
        remote: 'modals/add_event.php?start='+start+'&end='+end+'&id='+user_id
    });

}
```

It's opening modal dialog where I'm submitting calendar data and afterwards submitting data to DB via AJAX.. And after this point I can't figure out how to show newly added data without refreshing page.. Any help here?

Additionally: this is my AJAX call when submitting modal dialog form:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "ajax/add_event.php?start="+start.unix()+'&end='+end.unix()+'&id='+user_id,
    data : $("#smart-form-event").serialize(),
    success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Event added successfully",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-exclamation'></i> <i></i>",
            color : "#659265",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 4000
        });
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you submitting some kind of form when executing the add event function?

Comment: Yes, modal dialog consists of form, which I'm submitting via AJAX to DB.

Comment: Post the whole function of the form post please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call "refetchEvents" after you inserting new event
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

...
success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Event added successfully",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-exclamation'></i> <i></i>",
            color : "#659265",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 4000
        });
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }
...
```

Comment: Hey it worked, I've been trying to use refetchEvents but in wrong places.. Thank you very much!! Good job )

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `return false;`

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "ajax/add_event.php?start="+start.unix()+'&end='+end.unix()+'&id='+user_id,
    data : $("#smart-form-event").serialize(),
    success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Event added successfully",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-exclamation'></i> <i></i>",
            color : "#659265",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 4000
        });
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    }
});

return false;
```

The `return false;` must be inside the submit function.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){

    $ajax({...});

    return false;

});
```

Comment: try this way. I did not see the edited version before posting.

Comment: Nop, sadly it doesn't help too :(

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {

                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',strong text
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'

                    //,agendaWeek,agendaDay
                },


                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,


                events: myevents



            });
```